# Parse Omniauth JSON response. Hash key is variable, do not know how to access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, omniauth

I am receiving JSON data from Omniauth and parsing it into a hash, however the data is formatted such that the user ID, changed to "USER_ID" in the code below, is the key. I need to access the data to add uid, name, email etc to  make it accessible by the rails app, however I'm not sure how to do so since the key (USER_ID) will change with each user.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the raw JSON output:

```
{  
   "count":1,
   "users":{  
      "123":{  
         "full_name":"Bob",
         "email_address":"bob@bob.com",
         "id":"123"
      }
   },
   "results":[  
      {  
         "key":"users",
         "id":"123"
      }
   ]
}
```

The following is the output as it is currently processed.

```
{  
   "provider"   =>"omniauth_provider",
   "uid"   =>"",
   "info"  =>   {  
      "name"      =>nil,
      "email"     =>nil
   },
   "credentials"   =>   {  
      "token"      =>"987654321",
      "expires"    =>false
   },
   "extra"   =>   {  
      "raw_info"      =>      {  
         "count"         =>1,
         "users"         =>         {  
            "USER_ID"            =>            {  
               "full_name"               =>"Bob"
               "email_address"           =>"bob@bob.com",
               "id"                      =>"123"
            }
         },
         "results"         =>         [  
            {  
               "key"               =>"users",
               "id"                =>"123"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: IMHO it will help if you can edit your code to be the format what you send, receive, and want. Use USER_ID 123, name "Alice", email address "alice@example.com", and delete many of the fields that don't matter as much to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the JSON to a hash, and then use `values` to access the hash values, if it's guaranteed that there's always at most 1 results return, you can use this code:

```
require 'json'
response = %Q(
{  
   "count":1,
   "users":{  
      "123":{  
         "full_name":"Bob",
         "email_address":"bob@bob.com",
         "id":"123"
      }
   },
   "results":[  
      {  
         "key":"users",
         "id":"123"
      }
   ]
}

)
h = JSON.parse(response)
user_info = h["users"].values.first
user_info["full_name"]
user_info["email_address"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. how would I integrate that solution into the following code:

`uid { raw_info['id'].to_s } 

def raw_info
     @raw_info ||= access_token.get('https://somewebsite.com/api/v1/users/me.json').parsed
end `

Comment: What will be returned from access_token.get('https://somewebsite.com/api/v1/users/me.json').parsed ?

Comment: The raw JSON in my original post is returned by access_token.get().parsed. I've wrapped that in the raw_info method, which I'm calling later to get the name, email address etc.

Comment: try this: `JSON.prase(access_token.get('https://somewebsite.com/api/v1/users/me.json').parsed)["users"].values.first`